# Linux dd wiping security

Tags: security, dd

I have some questions regarding the "dd" utility, if someone can help. Please answer only if you are sure about the answer !

I have a scenario here in which I have a HDD with Bad Sectors that I need to wipe in order to archive it.
I want to decomission that respective HDD and I started to wipe it using one-pass zeros.

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda status=progress`

at exactly 3.7 GB in the Wipe (the HDD has 500 GB capacity), it always throws me a "I/O Error" and the dd utility exists.

I ASUME there is a Bad Sector or something there...

Now, I have multiple questions/issues:

1. Is there a method to WIPE ALL the sectors of that respective HDD, even if there are bad sectors ? Or at least SKIP the bad ones and continue wiping the rest of the HDD which has good sectors ?...
   Using "conv=noerror" in "dd" does NOT do the trick, because, as I understand, "conv=noerror" only skips information in the "if" device (input device), not on the "of" device (output device).
   I read something about ddrescue and badblocks, and so on, but I did not have a clear answer in my mind...
2. I read somewhere that "dd" is not such a great tool to wipe HDDs... To be more precise, I have heard that "dd" skips some sectors that the Harddisk may have reserved if they are bad sectors, for example.
   I need "DD" to access ALL my HDD space.

What I want to say is that I use "dd" for 15 years to wipe all my hdds. Very few of them threw the "I/O Error", and those HDDs were archived and never given away, exactly because of the uncertainty of full wiping... So I did not take any chance...
However, I had HDDs which I wiped completely and which didn't threw any I/O Errors.

Is there even a remote possibility that "DD" did not Wipe everything from these HDDs ?
If I used "dd" and it went ALL THE WAY, until it threw the "No space left on device" message, can I safely asume that it wiped ALL the harddisk space ?
Or even in these conditions, are there some sectors/blocks that might have been reserved and "dd" cannot touch these ? (in which case, it is a security concern)...

Thank you !

Adam.

Comment: With enough money, time, and high end software it might be possible to partially revert a dd.  But there is a simple solution: drive a couple of nails through the platters.

Comment: When you are this much concerned about your data beeing securely destroyed -> There are companies that physically shred harddrives into very small pieces...

Comment: Do a binary search for a starting block that is BEYOND the bad surface area.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do what you want is using the gnu utility gnu ddrescue (apt install gddrescue on a Debian / Ubuntu system). It is able to "skip" damaged sectors and also skip internal buffers with direct i/o and delete all sectors that are writable eluding the damaged ones. info ddrescue for docs and examples.